# Как можно сделать приватный репозиторий публичным на gitHube?

Tags: github

Вот это не работает
Справа в меню зайти в настройки "Settings" затем вкладка "Options" и в самом низу "Make this repository public".

"Make this repository public". - нет нигде такого

Comment: "Change visibility"

Answer (score 2):

На словах:

- Settings → Options
- Скролим в самый низ долго
- Видим секцию **Danger Zone** с опцией **Change repository visibility** и нажимаем кнопку **Change Visibility**
- Откроется модальное окно, где можно поменять приватность.

---

В картинках:

- Тыкаем так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Дальше скролим в саааааамый низ
- Далее:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]